# How to prevent pip from replacing numpy+mkl with just numpy when installing packages that require numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

When I `pip install` (or `pip install --upgrade`) packages that require `numpy`, they have a tendency to uninstall my existing `numpy+mkl` (which has a high enough version to satisfy the `numpy` version requirement). Afterwards, they install `numpy` without `+mkl`, which causes problems for other packages that do require MKL. An example for which this happens is [gym](https://github.com/openai/gym) (which has `'numpy>=1.10.4'` in its `install_requires` in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/setup.py)).

I understand that this is related to the `+mkl` suffix that probably somehow messes with the versions, and understand I can fix it afterwards by downloading and installing `numpy+mkl` from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, but it gets annoying to manually do this every time over again when upgrading a package like gym to a new version. **Is there any way to prevent `numpy+mkl` from getting uninstalled during the `pip install --upgrade`?**

---

For me, this is happening on **Windows 10**, **Python 3.6**. I did not yet check if the same happens on **Linux**, but would be interested in an answer for that too if it's different there.

My currently installed version of **`numpy+mkl`** (which often gets automatically uninstalled) is **`1.13.3+mkl`**.

Comment: Try the [`--upgrade-strategy`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-upgrade-strategy) option.

Comment: @cgohlke just tried it with latest release of gym which I did not yet have, worked perfectly! Would you mind writing it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`--upgrade-strategy`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-upgrade-strategy), as suggested by cgohlke in a comment, addresses this problem. So, taking the example where we want to install `gym` **from scratch** without it replacing our existing `numpy+mkl` installation with regular `numpy`, the full command to run is:

`pip install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed gym`

Or, if we just want to **upgrade an existing installation**, we also add `--upgrade`

`pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed gym`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some packages force pip to reinstall numpy. The safest (and only) way to ensure that numpy is installed with mkl (from conda) is to uninstall using conda and pip and then reinstall using conda:

```
conda uninstall numpy
pip uninstall nump
conda install numpy
```